Efficiently copying multiple sheets from multiple Excel files into a single Excel file
I am working on a Python project to merge multiple Excel files, where each file contains approximately 100 sheets. I need to merge these such that the resulting Excel file combines all sheets from the source files, maintaining their individual identity.
For instance, if 'excel_1.xlsx' contains sheets named '1' to '100' and 'excel_2.xlsx' contains sheets named '101' to '200', the merged file 'excel_merged.xlsx' should have sheets named from '1' to '200'.
However, my current Python code, which utilizes pandas and ExcelWriter, is inefficient as the time to merge files increases significantly with each additional file. The merging time seems to increase in an almost Fibonacci sequence. Here is my code:
import pandas as pd
import os
import time

# read excel file
excel_files = []
file_name = 'output_240326_pivot_{i}.xlsx'
for i in range(64):
    file_path = f'./our_data/240403/' + file_name.format(i=i)
    excel_files.append(file_path)

# final merging path
final_excel_path = './our_data/240403/240403_final_for_tgt.xlsx'

# start time count for total merging
start_time = time.time()

with pd.ExcelWriter(final_excel_path) as writer:
    # for each excel file
    for file in excel_files:
        # start time count
        file_start_time = time.time()
    
        # Read every sheets in excel file
        xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
        for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
            df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name)
            # Save each sheet seperately using ExcelWriter
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)
    
        # Time spent for merging current file
        file_end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Completed merging {os.path.basename(file)} in {file_end_time - file_start_time:.2f} seconds.")

# Total time for merging
end_time = time.time()
print(f"All sheets combined into {final_excel_path} in {end_time - start_time:.2f} seconds.")

Here are the time logs showing the increasing merge duration for each file:
Completed merging output_240326_pivot_0.xlsx in 0.64 seconds.
...
Completed merging output_240326_pivot_18.xlsx in 102.94 seconds.


Could this increasing delay be due to a growing overhead with ExcelWriter as more sheets are added? Would it be more efficient to first split each sheet into separate .csv files and then merge them into one Excel file? I couldn’t find specific advice for this scenario on Stack Overflow. Any insights or alternative approaches to improve the efficiency of this process would be greatly appreciated.

Just a guess but are you perhaps memory constrained? The writer instance will obviously "grow" as each spreadsheet is merged into it and if the individual spreadsheets are all large, it may consume a lot of memory

related and also pointing to memory issues: Algorithm becomes slow after a few excel files - Combining several SHEETS into one EXCEL

Processed 3 different files and merged their sheets into a single file. The only difference is the engine property in ExcelWriter. The code snippet:
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
# Path to the source Excel file
source_excel_path =[ 'data\Employee Data.xlsx', 'data\Employee Data 1.xlsx', 'data\Employee Data 2.xlsx']

# Path to the destination Excel file
destination_excel_path = 'new_excel_file.xlsx'


# Create a Pandas Excel writer using Openpyxl as the engine
with pd.ExcelWriter(destination_excel_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
    for file in source_excel_path:
        # start time count
        file_start_time = time.time()

        xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)

        for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
            # Read the specific sheet into a DataFrame
            df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name=sheet_name)

            # Write the DataFrame to the new Excel file using the same sheet name
            df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

        # Time spent for merging current file
        file_end_time = time.time()
        print(f"Completed merging {os.path.basename(sheet_name)} in {file_end_time - file_start_time:.2f} seconds.")

print("Sheets copied successfully.")

The processing time for each file is roughly the same.
Completed merging Sheet 5 in 0.64 seconds.
Completed merging Sheet 5 in 0.65 seconds.
Completed merging Sheet 15 in 0.68 seconds.
Sheets copied successfully.


Thanks for keep tracking the issues. I've tested with small set and it works well! I'm now running the code again with the full dataset. I'll let you know if it's done.

I guess the memory issue or something else still occurs. The time spent for merging keeps increasing as the original code with the same pattern. Sad news.

While I understand it's not suitable to request your actual data sheets, would it be possible for you to supply some large dummy files instead? I aim to conduct some tests to enhance processing times and will ensure to keep you updated on any advancements.

Thanks for keep tracking the issue. By the way, I can't provide you with our data because it's patient prescription data. Also currently I find that I don't need to merge the data because while training AI model, can just load data iteratively. Thanks :)

One potential performance issue I see in your code, is that you iterate over sheets of each workbook, when you read them.
The tips to avoid that, is to use :
df.read_excel(path, sheet_name=None)

As mentionned in the pandas documentation, using sheet_name=None allows to read all worksheets in one time, this will prevents from opening and closing the workbook that your are reading, each time you need to access a worksheet.
The result is that you get all your worksheets into a Dict[str, pd.Dataframe], where str are the names of your worksheet.
Here is the code allowing you to read all your workbooks:
df_workbooks: List[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]] = [
    pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=None)
    for path in excel_files
]

From now, i'm considering that there is no sheet name duplicate accross all you workbooks. If so, you'll have to rename them in the list above, or you'll have to merge them with pd.concat()
Once you have them, if you want to merge them into a single excel file, pandas tells you here that you have no other way to use pd.ExcelWriter as you did it :
io_buffer = BytesIO()

with pd.ExcelWriter(io_buffer) as writer:
    for workbook in df_workbooks:
        for sheet_name, worksheet_df in workbook.items():
            worksheet_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

Here, I use a BytesIO object, to perform the merging operations in memory, without opening a file for writing. It is not mandatory, just something I like to do because it prevents errors from happening while a file stream is open.
Now that you have your BytesIO object fullfilled, you can write it on the location you want, as a classic file writing:
with open(final_excel_path, "wb") as writer:
    writer.write(io_buffer.getbuffer())

Here is the full code:
import pandas as pd
import os
import time
from io import BytesIO
from typing import Dict, List

excel_files = ["workbook_a.xlsx", "workbook_b.xlsx"]
final_excel_path = "merged.xlsx"

# this should work with openpyxl, but i personnaly prefer this one (Note that you'll need to run pip install xlsxwriter to use this one)
XL_ENGINE = "xlsxwriter"

if __name__ == "__main__":

    # start time count for total merging
    start_time = time.time()

    df_workbooks: List[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]] = [
        pd.read_excel(path, sheet_name=None)
        for path in excel_files
    ]

    io_buffer = BytesIO()

    with pd.ExcelWriter(io_buffer, engine=XL_ENGINE) as writer:
        for workbook in df_workbooks:
            for sheet_name, worksheet_df in workbook.items():
                worksheet_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

    with open(final_excel_path, "wb") as writer:
        writer.write(io_buffer.getbuffer())

    # Total time for merging
    print(f"All sheets combined into {final_excel_path} in {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds.")



Step 2: read you files asynchronoulsy
A more complex solution, but very efficient to read a lot of files faster, is to use aiofiles and asyncio to read your files asynchronously.
The tip is to read your excel files as binary files, then to parse these bytes with pd.read_excel:
async with aiofiles.open(path, "rb") as reader:

    # using BytesIO is recommanded by pandas
    bytes_content = BytesIO(await reader.read())

    dataframes: Dict[str, pd.DataFrame] = pd.read_excel(bytes_content, sheet_name=None)

Here is an implementation for your example: (I don't give more explainations about the async tasks working, as it is not the topic, and this post is long enough...)
from typing import Dict, List
from io import BytesIO
import pandas as pd
import aiofiles
import asyncio
import time

excel_files = ["workbook_a.xlsx", "workbook_b.xlsx"]
final_excel_path = "merged.xlsx"

XL_ENGINE = "xlsxwriter"


async def read_workbook_task(path: str, workbooks: list) -> Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]:

    async with aiofiles.open(path, "rb") as reader:

        bytes_content = BytesIO(await reader.read())

        workbooks.append(pd.read_excel(bytes_content, sheet_name=None))


async def read_workbooks_async() -> List[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]]:
    workbooks_df = []

    tasks = [
        asyncio.create_task(read_workbook_task(path, workbooks_df))
        for path in excel_files
    ]

    await asyncio.gather(*tasks)

    return workbooks_df


def merge_workbooks(workbooks_df: List[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]]) -> BytesIO:
    io_buffer = BytesIO()

    with pd.ExcelWriter(io_buffer, engine=XL_ENGINE) as writer:
        for workbook in workbooks_df:
            for sheet_name, worksheet_df in workbook.items():
                worksheet_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet_name, index=False)

    return io_buffer


async def main():

    # start time count for total merging
    start_time = time.time()

    workbooks_df = await read_workbooks_async()

    io_buffer = merge_workbooks(workbooks_df)

    with open(final_excel_path, "wb") as writer:
        writer.write(io_buffer.getbuffer())

    # Total time for merging
    print(f"All sheets combined into {final_excel_path} in {time.time() - start_time:.2f} seconds.")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())



The complexity seems to be increasing as the operations gets intensive. There is a nested for loop and you are opening the same file within the for loop. You can optimize this be collating all the sheets from all the files into a single dataframe and then convert it to excel at the end. Refer the sample code for this:
all_sheets = []
for file in files:
  xls = pd.ExcelFile(file)
  for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name)
    all_sheets.append(df)
merged_df = pd.concat(all_sheets, ignore_index=True)
merged_df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Combined_Sheet", index=False)
writer.save()


Thanks for your advice! I'm retrying it with fixed code.

is this not merging sheets? thought OP wanted to assemble all sheets in a single file without altering any sheet.

@Oca Yes, the code Siddhartha Sengupta written makes all the sheets merged into one sheet in one file. I want each sheets seperately merged into one file..

@James Jang, I am extremely sorry for the previous version I have edited the answer now which takes each sheet separately. One question here is can that can the sheet names in different files be of the same name?

@SiddharthaSengupta No worries, thanks for helping me. By the way, I didn't understand well what your question means. Do you mean that is it ok to change the sheet name when merging the file? If yes, that's right.

Since your update, your code now concatenate all sheets from a list of files into a single sheet. That is still not what OP asked for.

Rather than employing the ExcelWriter, utilize the built-in iteration capabilities of pandas for Excel sheets. Here is an example code snippet:
import pandas as pd
import time
import os
# The path to your Excel file
excel_file_path = "data\Employee Data.xlsx"

# Load the Excel file
xls = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file_path)

# List to hold data from each sheet
all_data = []

# Loop through each sheet in the Excel file
for sheet_name in xls.sheet_names:
    # start time count
    file_start_time = time.time()
    # Load the sheet into a DataFrame
    df = pd.read_excel(xls, sheet_name)
    # Append the data from this sheet to the list
    all_data.append(df)
    # Time spent for merging current file
    file_end_time = time.time()
    print(f"Completed merging {os.path.basename(sheet_name)} in {file_end_time - file_start_time:.2f} seconds.")

# Concatenate all the dataframes in the list into a single dataframe
merged_data = pd.concat(all_data)

# Optional: If you want to ignore the index or want a continuous index
merged_data.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Save the merged data to a new Excel file
merged_data.to_excel('data/merged_excel_file.xlsx', index=False)

I executed the script across 5 sheets within a single Excel file, each containing 11 columns and 1000 records.
Completed merging Sheet 1 in 0.05 seconds.
Completed merging Sheet 2 in 0.05 seconds.
Completed merging Sheet 3 in 0.06 seconds.
Completed merging Sheet 4 in 0.05 seconds.
Completed merging Sheet 5 in 0.05 seconds.

Processing time for each sheet was roughly the same.

Nowhere has OP asked for merging or concatenating sheets. The request is assemble them in a single file, that's all.

Yes, the ultimate objective is to consolidate the results into a single file. Try this code snippet on your file. The sheets can be skipped or picked conditionally.

Hi, and welcome to SO. Yes, but no: please read the request carefully. Your code concatenates all sheets of a single file into one sheet. That is not the request.

My bad, I ran almost a similar script with just one change. Added engine property to the pd.ExcelWriter.
with pd.ExcelWriter(destination_excel_path, engine='openpyxl') as writer:
Can you try this?

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
